# Can't figure out what flattnes parameter does in PathIterator?

Tags: java, swing, shapes, path-iterator

I am writing my own `PathIterator` implementation.

Currently I implemented method with flatness with flatness-less one:

```
@Override
public PathIterator getPathIterator(AffineTransform at, double flatness) {
    return getPathIterator(at);
}
```

i.e. I am ignoring it.

What is the simplest way to work with `flatness` parameter?

My current iterator gives a series of parallel vertical lines (not connected between). How important for me to implement flatness-aware version of the iterator? Where is it used?

Answer (score 3):

The [`getPathIterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#getPathIterator%28java.awt.geom.AffineTransform,%20double%29) cited should return only `SEG_MOVETO`, `SEG_LINETO`, and `SEG_CLOSE` segment types. If your `Shape` has no other segment types, e.g. `SEG_CUBICTO` or `SEG_QUADTO`, the `flatness` is irrelevant. As a concrete example, the [`Rectangle2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html) implementation specifies that "Since rectangles are already flat, the flatness parameter is ignored."